# StreamReader function cannot understand string variable

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, streamreader

I'm using VB .Net for Windows Phone 8.
I'm trying to get first line from txt file.
Txt file is located in Web.

```
Dim path As String
path="http://web.com/text.txt"

Using TXT As New StreamReader(path)
    TextBox1.Text = TXT.ReadLine()
End Using
```

And I get Error Message in this line `Using TXT As New StreamReader(path)`

> Value of type 'String' cannot be converted to 'System.IO.Stream'

How can I set path to the file without using of String variable?

Comment: Use a WebRequest if you want to read from an url.

Comment: I agree with Tim. If you want to be fancy, Make a web service that does this for you and only return a value.. Remember that you must have as little  code on the device as possible, this makes your app faster..

Comment: Is the code complete? The typing seems to be OK unless you omitted something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim httpClient As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
Dim form As New MultipartFormDataContent()
Dim getUrl As String = "http://website/test.txt"
            Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await httpClient.PostAsync(getUrl, form)
            responseText = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
```

This one is working well

Answer (score 0):

Using simply txt.ReadToEnd to read all string that's all

Comment: I get an error before i can use txt.ReadToEnd. I get it here: Using TXT As New StreamReader(path)

Comment: Sorry Arthur i was a little bit busy, you're issue(and i see it now) it that you're trying toread from an url.you need to download the file into your computer or using an httpwebrequest read the stream and the update the control.You cannot do it before

Comment: I have used this one: Dim httpClient As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
            Dim form As New MultipartFormDataContent()

            Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await httpClient.PostAsync(getUrl, form)
            responseText = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()

Answer (score 0):

You should use HttpWebRequest to get stuff back from a URL, so something like this...

```
Imports System.Net
```

then

```
Dim wRequest As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.bbc.co.uk/news")

wRequest.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
wRequest.Accept = "application/text"
wRequest.Method = "GET"

Dim wResponse As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(wRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

Using srRead As New StreamReader(wResponse.GetResponseStream())
    Dim sResponse As String = srRead.ReadToEnd()
End Using
```

Comment: I get error message for this string of your code: Dim wResponse As HttpWebResponse = wRequest.GetResponse(); Error is: 'GetResponse' is not a member of 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest'

Comment: Really? It works just fine here. What version of .Net are you using? You may need to include a reference to System.Net, though I haven't. Try a DirectCast (see above)

Comment: System.Net is Imported and DirectCast doesn't help. I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0 and NET.Framework 4.5

Comment: No, not an Imports a **Reference**. I'll try it in VS2012 and 4.5. Hang on.

Comment: I've tried it in VS2012 and 4.5 and it works just fine. Take the code snippet out into a console app and see if that runs. If so then you may have a conflict somewhere.

Comment: I have not VS2012, but VS2013 version 12.0; Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013
Version 12.0.30501.00 Update 2
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.51641

Comment: Don't have that I'm afraid, maybe someone else can help. This works just fine in VS2008 and VS2012. Sorry.